# How to remove # from url in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, hash

My Urls are generated like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/?course_id=5324#review_125
```

Page is scrolled to that particular div using `anchorScroll`.(I have reviewlist and used hash to scroll to that review)

But when someone click on sort reviews, i want to remove hash to prevent scroll.

i have tried `$location.hash(null)` and `$location.hash(null)` but it is not removing # from url.

after `$location.hash(null)` i get url like `http://localhost:3000/?course_id=5324#`

**I want solution to remove hash from url.**

Comment: you could see here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4568#issuecomment-106621383 its resolved here, basically you need to `$anchorScroll('some-hash')` will not change your `location.hash`

Comment: @InsaneSkulll, i know that search engine can help and thanks for providing link,but link is useless.